# Python: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. Error while solving simple ode

Tags: python, ode, differential-equations

I have written a simple python code to simulate adaptive fuzzy sliding mode control. My problem is no matter what I do, I get this error. I tried converting list to arrays etc. But to no effect. Kindly help me iron out this issue. What I am trying to do, is, I have created a function that returns 53 elements and then the ode method of scipy integrates it.

Here is my code. PFA-

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import ode
from numpy import exp,sin,cos,concatenate,transpose,pi,tanh
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

c,eta,k,gamma1,gamma2,gamma3,gamma4,gamma5,gamma21,gamma22,gamma23,gamma24,gamma25=2,1.5,2,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
x=np.linspace(0,10,100)
xdot=np.linspace(0,10,100)
def member(x,z):
    return exp(-((x+z)/(pi/24))**2)
m=[]
b=[pi/6,pi/12,0,-pi/12,-pi/6]

def f(t,Y):
    x1,x2,x3,eta1,eta2,eta3,eta4,eta5,eta6,eta7,eta8,eta9,eta10,eta11,eta12,eta13,eta14,eta15,eta16,eta17,eta18,eta19,eta20,eta21,eta22,eta23,eta24,eta25,geta1,geta2,geta3,geta4,geta5,geta6,geta7,geta8,geta9,geta10,geta11,geta12,geta13,geta14,geta15,geta16,geta17,geta18,geta19,geta20,geta21,geta22,geta23,geta24,geta25=Y
    eta=np.array([eta1,eta2,eta3,eta4,eta5,eta6,eta7,eta8,eta9,eta10,eta11,eta12,eta13,eta14,eta15,eta16,eta17,eta18,eta19,eta20,eta21,eta22,eta23,eta24,eta25])
    geta=np.array([geta1,geta2,geta3,geta4,geta5,geta6,geta7,geta8,geta9,geta10,geta11,geta12,geta13,geta14,geta15,geta16,geta17,geta18,geta19,geta20,geta21,geta22,geta23,geta24,geta25])
    m,z=[],[]
    for i in range(5):
        for j in range(5):
            m.append(member(x1,b[i])*member(x2,b[j]))
    for i in range(25):
        z.append(m[i]/sum(m))
    z=np.array(z)
    e,de=x1-sin(t),x2-cos(t)
    s=de+c**2*x3+2*c*e
    f=np.dot(eta,z)
    g=np.dot(geta,z)
    u=(1./g)*(-f-c**2*e-2*c*de-sin(t)-eta*tanh(s)-k*s)
    x1dot=x2
    x2dot=f+g*u
    x3dot=e
    eta1dot,eta2dot,eta3dot,eta4dot,eta5dot,eta6dot,eta7dot,eta8dot,eta9dot,eta10dot,eta11dot,eta12dot,eta13dot,eta14dot,eta15dot,eta16dot,eta17dot,eta18dot,eta19dot,eta20dot,eta21dot,eta22dot,eta23dot,eta24dot,eta25dot,geta1dot,geta2dot,geta3dot,geta4dot,geta5dot,geta6dot,geta7dot,geta8dot,geta9dot,geta10dot,geta11dot,geta12dot,geta13dot,geta14dot,geta15dot,geta16dot,geta17dot,geta18dot,geta19dot,geta20dot,geta21dot,geta22dot,geta23dot,geta24dot,geta25dot=-2*s*z[0],-2*s*z[1],-2*s*z[2],-2*s*z[3],-2*s*z[4],-2*s*z[5],-2*s*z[6],-2*s*z[7],-2*s*z[8],-2*s*z[9],-2*s*z[10],-2*s*z[11],-2*s*z[12],-2*s*z[13],-2*s*z[14],-2*s*z[15],-2*s*z[16],-2*s*z[17],-2*s*z[18],-2*s*z[19],-2*s*z[20],-2*s*z[21],-2*s*z[22],-2*s*z[23],-2*s*z[24],-3*s*z[0]*u,-3*s*z[1]*u,-3*s*z[2]*u,-3*s*z[3]*u,-3*s*z[4]*u,-3*s*z[5]*u,-3*s*z[6]*u,-3*s*z[7]*u,-3*s*z[8]*u,-3*s*z[9]*u,-3*s*z[10]*u,-3*s*z[11]*u,-3*s*z[12]*u,-3*s*z[13]*u,-3*s*z[14]*u,-3*s*z[15]*u,-3*s*z[16]*u,-3*s*z[17]*u,-3*s*z[18]*u,-3*s*z[19]*u,-3*s*z[20]*u,-3*s*z[21]*u,-3*s*z[22]*u,-3*s*z[23]*u,-3*s*z[24]*u
    return[x1dot,x2dot,x3dot,eta1dot,eta2dot,eta3dot,eta4dot,eta5dot,eta6dot,eta7dot,eta8dot,eta9dot,eta10dot,eta11dot,eta12dot,eta13dot,eta14dot,eta15dot,eta16dot,eta17dot,eta18dot,eta19dot,eta20dot,eta21dot,eta22dot,eta23dot,eta24dot,eta25dot,geta1dot,geta2dot,geta3dot,geta4dot,geta5dot,geta6dot,geta7dot,geta8dot,geta9dot,geta10dot,geta11dot,geta12dot,geta13dot,geta14dot,geta15dot,geta16dot,geta17dot,geta18dot,geta19dot,geta20dot,geta21dot,geta22dot,geta23dot,geta24dot,geta25dot]
Y,t=[],[]
for i in range(50):
    Y.append(0.1)
#Y=np.array(Y)
y0=[0,0,0]
y0=y0+Y
t0=0
def int_amar():
    t1,dt=10,.01
    x=[]
    for i in range(53):
        x.append([])
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    odee=ode(f).set_integrator('dopri5',method='bdf',nsteps=1e6)
    odee.set_initial_value(y0,t0)
    while odee.successful() and odee.t<t1:
        odee.integrate(odee.t+dt)
        for i in range(53):
            x[i].append(odee.y[i])
        t.append(odee.t)
    #for i in range(53):
    #    x[i]=np.array(x[i])


    print(x1.shape)
    return x

def main():
    fun=int_amar()
    Z,f,g,m=[[],[],[],[],[]],[],[],[]
    for i in range(5):
        for j in range(5):
            m.append(member(fun[0],b[i])*member(fun[1],b[j]))
    for i in range(25):
        Z[i].append(m[i]/sum(m))


    zetta1,zetta2,zetta3,zetta4,zetta5,zetta6,zetta7,zetta8,zetta9,zetta10,zetta11,zetta12,zetta13,zetta14,zetta15,zetta16,zetta17,zetta18,zetta19,zetta20,zetta21,zetta22,zetta23,zetta24,zetta25=Z[0],Z[1],Z[2],Z[3],Z[4],Z[5],Z[6],Z[7],Z[8],Z[9],Z[10],Z[11],Z[12],Z[13],Z[14],Z[15],Z[16],Z[17],Z[18],Z[19],Z[20],Z[21],Z[22],Z[23],Z[24],Z[25]
    e=fun[0]-sin(t)
    s=fun[1]+c**2*fun[2]+2*c*e

    for i in range(len(fun[2])):
        f.append(np.dot(np.array([[fun[3][i],fun[4][i],fun[5][i],fun[6][i],fun[7][i],fun[8][i],fun[9][i],fun[10][i],fun[11][i],fun[12][i],fun[13][i],fun[14][i],fun[15][i],fun[16][i],fun[17][i],fun[18][i],fun[19][i],fun[20][i],fun[21][i],fun[22][i],fun[23][i],fun[24][i],fun[25][i],fun[26][i],fun[27][i]]]),np.array([[zetta1[i]],[zetta2[i]],[zetta3[i]],[zetta4[i]],[zetta5[i]],[zetta6[i]],[zetta7[i]],[zetta8[i]],[zetta9[i]],[zetta10[i]],[zetta11[i]],[zetta12[i]],[zetta13[i]],[zetta14[i]],[zetta15[i]],[zetta16[i]],[zetta17[i]],[zetta18[i]],[zetta19[i]],[zetta20[i]],[zetta21[i]],[zetta22[i]],[zetta23[i]],[zetta24[i]],[zetta25[i]]]))) 
        g.append(np.dot(np.array([[fun[28][i],fun[29][i],fun[30][i],fun[31][i],fun[32][i],fun[33][i],fun[34][i],fun[35][i],fun[36][i],fun[37][i],fun[38][i],fun[39][i],fun[40][i],fun[41][i],fun[42][i],fun[43][i],fun[44][i],fun[45][i],fun[46][i],fun[47][i],fun[48][i],fun[49][i],fun[50][i],fun[51][i],fun[52][i]]]),np.array([[zetta1[i]],[zetta2[i]],[zetta3[i]],[zetta4[i]],[zetta5[i]],[zetta6[i]],[zetta7[i]],[zetta8[i]],[zetta9[i]],[zetta10[i]],[zetta11[i]],[zetta12[i]],[zetta13[i]],[zetta14[i]],[zetta15[i]],[zetta16[i]],[zetta17[i]],[zetta18[i]],[zetta19[i]],[zetta20[i]],[zetta21[i]],[zetta22[i]],[zetta23[i]],[zetta24[i]],[zetta25[i]]]))) 


    f,g=np.array(f),np.array(g)
    u=(1./g)*(-f-c*e-sin(t)-eta*tanh(s)-k*s)
    print(u.shape)
    for i in range(12):
        plt.subplot(3,4,i+1)
        plt.plot(t,fun[i])
    #plt.figure(2)
    #plt.plot(t,u)
    plt.show()
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You should take a look at [ask] and [MCVE].

Comment: if you have single tuple in an np.array then you should use ([ brackets instead of ([[

Comment: This code is terribly written. Please refactor it to a form that can be read by others.

Comment: Stop using a bazillion numbered variables and 1040-character lines, and you'll have a much easier time debugging your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is on line 30:

`u=(1./g)*(-f-c**2*e-2*c*de-sin(t)-eta*tanh(s)-k*s)`

`eta` is an array but the rest of the terms are scalars. This causes `u` to be an array and the resulting return list has a mix of scalars and arrays.

You probably mistyped the equation here.

Comment: Oh gosh! Damn you're right! That was a typo, to be honest, eta with tanh should be just a scalar=1.5, whereas in my code it was taking it to be an array, I guess!